# Disable automatic conversion of non-boolean values to boolean with Jackson

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I'm looking for a way to disable non-bool values to be used inside a request body. For example:

```
{
  "prop": 23
}
```

would be converted by jackson into `true` for `myprop` inside MyPjo:

```
 public ResponseEntity action(@RequestBody @Valid MyPojo myPojo) {

 }

public class MyPojo {

    @NotNull
    private final boolean myprop;

    @JsonCreator
    public MyPojo(@JsonProperty(value = "prop", required = true) boolean myprop) {
        this.myprop = myprop;
    }
}
```

What would be the best way to disable non-bool values for `myprop`, and just thrown exception when that happens?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way in this case for all fields that are validated,  you consider this custom validation. 
You can create a custom constraint for Boolean values,  something like this:
    https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html#validator-customconstraints

So you can add your custom constraint on your field

```
    @ValidBoolean
    private boolean isReal;
```